# How to preload generated styles and scripts?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I'm trying to preload my main css and js files - these files are generated using the AdvAgg module.

I've tried using the `hook_preprocess_html` in a theme and in a module, but in the `$variables['page']['#attached']['html_head_link']` array, the styles and scripts aren't there.

What is the best way to access these file details, so I can create the necessary `rel="preload"` links?

Comment: You wouldn't add rel="preload" to your <script> elements. You add it as its own <link> element in the <head> so it's a standalone tag. Here's more info/examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: @Leigh good point - I've reworded the question, as the issue still remains (how can I know what preload links to create)

Comment: I'd say you'd probably need to manually work that out and add the ones you know are on all pages. The on ones that aren't you could add the <link> in the render array when you know the relevant library is added (e.g. in a custom block/controller you could add $build[‘#attached’][‘head_link’] = $mylinkarray and that will still add it into <head>). You also mentioned you're using AdvAgg i'm pretty sure there's an option in the settings to do the preconnects/preloads automatically it might be worth looking in there

Comment: @Leigh the issue is that the file names that AdvAgg module generates basically consist of a random string - and those files aren't available in the `hook_preprocess_html` hook. I think the option to pre-fetch is only there in AdvAgg if you enable critical css functionality, which I'm not currently leveraging.

Comment: AdvAgg itself does this with regular expressions against the full response HTML (see the `DeferCss` and `DeferJs` classes in the `Drupal\advagg_mod\Asset` namespace). If there was an easier way (using the AdvAgg API for example), I'm sure it would be used there. So I think the approach is to implement your own response subscriber, and string-replace the HTML as necessary :/

Comment: @Clive thanks for the info. The solution sounds pretty nasty :/

Comment: You could always load the HTML into a `DOMDocument` and do it a bit more cleanly, but yeah, either way it's not ideal

Comment: @Clive I may just do a pull request to the AdvAgg project :)